# What is the idiomatic way of counting the number of elements matching predicate?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a better way to count the number of elements for which the predicate function is true, other than this:

```
PredCount[lst_, pred_] := Length@Select[lst, pred];
```

I'm asking because it seems inefficient to construct a subset of `lst` with `Select[]`, and because `Count[]` only works with patterns. In my use case, the function `PredCount` is called many times with a large `lst`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can often do this by turning your predicate into a pattern with a condition.  For example:

```
Count[list, x_/;x>5]
```

would count the number of elements in list which are greater than 5.

Comment: Aha! Any reason not to generalize this to `Count[lst, x_ /; pred[x]]` and be done with it?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html)

```
PredCount = Count[#, _?#2] &;

PredCount[Range@30, PrimeQ]
```

> ```
> (*out*) 10
> ```

This pattern is simple enough that you might use `Count` directly.