# Fastest way to count elements matching predicate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Earlier today I asked if there's an [idiomatic way to count elements matching predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344339/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-counting-the-number-of-elements-matching-predicate) function in Mathematica, as I was concerned with performance.

My initial approach for a given predicate `pred` was the following:

```
PredCount1[lst_, pred_] := Length@Select[lst, pred];
```

and I got a suggestion to instead use

```
PredCount2[lst_, pred_] := Count[lst, x_/;pred@x];
```

I started profiling these functions, with different `lst` sizes and `pred` functions, and added two more definitions:

```
PredCount3[lst_, pred_] := Count[Thread@pred@lst, True];
PredCount4[lst_, pred_] := Total[If[pred@#, 1, 0] & /@ lst];
```

My data samples were ranges between 1 and 10 million elements, and my test functions were `EvenQ`, `#<5&` and `PrimeQ`. The following graphs demonstrate time taken.

**EvenQ**
[image: EvenQ predicate]

PredCount2 is slowest, 3 and 4 duke it out.

**Comparison predicate: #<5&**

I've selected this function, because it's close to what I need in my actual problem. Don't worry that this is a silly test function, it actually proves that the 4th function has some merit, which I actually ended up using it in my solution.

[image: Less than five predicate]

Same as `EvenQ`, but 3 is clearly slower than 4.

**PrimeQ**
[image: PrimeQ predicate]

This is just bizarre. Everything is flipped. I'm not suspecting caching as the culprit here, since worst values are for the function computed last.

So, what's the right (fastest) way to count the number of elements in a list, that match a given predicate function?

Comment: Are you using Timing[] or AbsoluteTime[] ? Please post your timing function!

Comment: What type of elements does the list you want to count over contain, Reals/Integers may perform differently?.

Comment: I use //Timing and the lists are generated with Range@num, and contain integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the result of auto-compilation.

First, for a `Listable` function such as `EvenQ` and `PrimeQ` use of `Thread` is unnecessary:

```
EvenQ[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {False, True, False}
> ```

This also explains why `PredCount3` performs well on these functions. (They are internally optimized for threading over a list.)

Now let us look at timings.

```
dat = RandomInteger[1*^6, 1*^6];

test = # < 5 &;

First@Timing[#[dat, test]] & /@ {PredCount1, PredCount2, PredCount3, PredCount4}
```

> ```
> {0.343, 0.437, 0.25, 0.047}
> ```

If we change a System Option to prevent auto-compilation within `Map` and run the test again:

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> Infinity}]

First@Timing[#[dat, test]] & /@ {PredCount1, PredCount2, PredCount3, PredCount4}
```

> ```
> {0.343, 0.452, 0.234, 0.765}
> ```

You can clearly see that without compilation `PredCount4` is much slower.  In short, if your test function can be compiled by *Mathematica* this is a good option.

[Here are some other examples of fast counting using numeric functions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027120/618728)

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense; I was hoping that there would be a simple universal method for doing this, as I'm surely you agree PredCount4 isn't very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the integers in the list can have a significant effect on the achievable timings. The use of `Tally` can improve performance if the range of the integers is constrained.

```
(* Count items in the list matching predicate, pred *)

PredCountID[lst_, pred_] := 
Select[Tally@lst, pred@First@# &]\[Transpose] // Last // Total

(* Define the values over which to check timings  *)
ranges = {100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000};
sizes = {100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000,100000000};
```

For PrimeQ this function gives the following timings:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Showing that even in a 10^8 sized list, Primes can be counted in less than a tenth of a second if they are from the set of integers, of {0,...,100000} and below the resolution of `Timing` if they are within a small range such as 1 to 100.

Because the predicate only has to be applied over the set of `Tally` values, this approach is relatively insensitive to the exact predicate function.